# enum and static const member variable usage in template trait class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overload-resolution

I want to test whether a class is streamable to `ostream&` by seeing whether an overload for `operator<<` is provided. Based on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534041/how-to-check-whether-operator-exists) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768511/using-sfinae-to-check-for-global-operator), I tried to write another version using C++11. This is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace TEST{
  class NotDefined{};

  template<typename T> 
  NotDefined& operator << (::std::ostream&, const T&);

  template <typename T>
  struct StreamInsertionExists {
    static std::ostream &s;
    static T const &t;
    enum { value = std::is_same<decltype(s << t), NotDefined>() };
  };
}

struct A{
  int val;
    friend ::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream&, const A&);
};

::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& os, const A& a)
{
  os << a.val;
  return os;
}

struct B{};

int main() {
  std::cout << TEST::StreamInsertionExists<A>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << TEST::StreamInsertionExists<B>::value << std::endl;

}
```

But this fails to compile:

> ```
> test_oper.cpp:40:57: error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?  
>   std::cout << TEST::StreamInsertionExists<A>::value << std::endl;  
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:1020:1: note:  
>   possible target for call  
>     endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)  
>
> test_oper.cpp:30:17: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'TEST::NotDefined' to '::std::ostream &'  
>   (aka 'basic_ostream<char> &') for 1st argument  
> ::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& os, const A& a)  
>
> test_oper.cpp:15:15: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'  
>   NotDefined& operator << (::std::ostream&, const T&);
> ```

However, if I replace the line
`enum { value = std::is_same<decltype(s << t), NotDefined>() };`
with
`static const bool value = std::is_same<decltype(s << t), NotDefined>();`
then everything compiles.

Why is there such a difference between the `enum` and the `bool`?

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you're trying to do, but `decltype(s << t)` should produce a `NotDefined&`, so this is maybe not what you are aiming for in the comparison with `NotDefined` via `std::is_same`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value` is an enum of anonymous name in `StreamInsertionExists<T>`. When you try to do:

```
std::cout << StreamInsertionExists<T>::value;
```

The compiler is doing overload lookup on `operator<<(std::ostream&, StreamInsertionExists<T>::E)`. In the typical case, it'd do integral promotion on the `enum` and stream it as `int`. However, you additionally defined this operator:

```
template<typename T> 
NotDefined& operator << (std::ostream&, const T&);
```

That is a better match for the `enum` than the `int` version (Exact Match vs integral promotion), so it is preferred. Yes, it's a function template, but non-templates are only preferred if the conversion sequences match - and in this case they don't.

Thus, this line:

```
std::cout << TEST::StreamInsertionExists<A>::value << std::endl;
```

which is:

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, TEST::StreamInsertionExists<A>::value), std::endl);
```

And the inner most `operator<<` call will use your `NotDefined&` template. Thus, the next step would be to find an appropriate function call for:

```
operator<<(NotDefined&, std::endl);
```

and there is no such overload for `operator<<` hence the error.

If you change `value` to be `bool`, there is no such problem because there *is* an `operator<<` that takes `bool` exactly: [#6](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). That said, even with `bool`, your trait is still incorrect as it always returns `false`. Your `NotDefined` version actually returns a reference, so you'd have to check against that. And also, `NotDefined&` means **not** defined, so you'd have to flip the sign:

```
static const bool value = !std::is_same<decltype(s << t), NotDefined&>();
```

However, this is particularly error prone. Now `cout << B{};` instead of failing to compile would instead give you a linker error, and `cout << B{} << endl;` gives you the same confusing overload error involving `endl` instead of simply statying that you can't stream a `B`.

You should prefer to just do:

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct stream_insertion_exists : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct stream_insertion_exists<T, void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>())
> > : std::true_type { };
```

Comment: Thank you!!
Your code works fine for me.  
But I have another question:  
If I want to use cout when << operator is defined,   
how should I use this code?  
This won't compile:
`if (!stream_insertion_exists<B>::value) {  
    std::cout << b << std::endl;   
  }`