# Can I have a single template with a variable object?

Tags: c++, templates

I currently have the following code:

```
template< class Obj, class ObjResult >
CLStatus convertObjToResult2( const Obj & xFrom, ObjResult & xTo )
{
    CLStatus eStatus = CLSTATUS_SUCCESS;
    switch ( xTo.eType )
    {
        case CEPTFull:
            xTo.xData.xFull = xFrom;
            break;
        case CEPTBrief:
            eStatus = Convert( xFrom, xTo.xData.xBrief );
            break;
        default:
            eStatus = CLSTATUS_INVALIDPROJECTIONTYPE;
    }
    return eStatus;
}

template< class Obj, class ObjResult >
CLStatus convertObjToResult1( const Obj & xFrom, ObjResult & xTo )
{
    CLStatus eStatus = CLSTATUS_SUCCESS;
    switch ( xTo.eType )
    {
        case CEPTFull:
            xTo.xData.xFull = xFrom;
            break;
        default:
            eStatus = CLSTATUS_INVALIDPROJECTIONTYPE;
    }
    return eStatus;
}
```

All ObjResults have an `xFull`, but only some have an `xBrief`, where xData is a `union`. This resulted in me writing the two different templates above, but it would be great if I could somehow have just one template.

I can't simply use `convertObjToResult2`, since it will fail to compile with object types that do not have an `xBrief`. I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768511/using-sfinae-to-check-for-global-operator) to see if it would help, but I don't understand at all what it's doing.

Comment: Overload `Convert` and pass `xTo.xData`?

Comment: That Convert function is already overloaded 100 times or so. Not a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `C++` [does not and won't have](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3613.pdf) a `static if` feature, you need a work around.

If you can't overload `Convert` as you said in comments, I thought of a layer above it which can be specialized depending on if `ObjResult` has the member or not.

```
template <class Obj, class ObjResult, class = void>
struct ConvertIfHasBrief {
  static auto Convert(Obj const &, ObjResult &) -> CLStatus  {
      return {};// dymmy value, not used
   }
};

template <class Obj, class ObjResult>
struct ConvertIfHasBrief <Obj, ObjResult,
                          std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<ObjResult>().xData.xBrief)>> {
  static auto Convert(Obj const &xFrom, ObjResult &xTo) {
    return ::Convert(xFrom, xTo.xData.xBrief);
  }
};



template< class Obj, class ObjResult>
CLStatus convertObjToResult( const Obj & xFrom, ObjResult & xTo )
{
    CLStatus eStatus = CLSTATUS_SUCCESS;
    switch ( xTo.eType )
    {
        case CEPTFull:
            xTo.xData.xFull = xFrom;
            break;
        case CEPTBrief:
                eStatus = ConvertIfHasBrief<Obj, ObjResult>::Convert(xFrom, xTo);
            break;
        default:
            eStatus = CLSTATUS_INVALIDPROJECTIONTYPE;
    }
    return eStatus;
}
```

[std::void_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) is not yet part of the standard, but the implementation is simple and can be found on the linked page. Just be sure not to declare it on the `std` namespace.

[proof it works](https://ideone.com/w8FfmT)

Comment: i don't thing this is correct, since `if (hasXBrief)` is not checked while compile time.

Comment: That doesn't handle the compile error at `xTo.xData.xBrief`

Comment: @JesseJ you said `xData` is a union. Then it has both members. Why would it be a compile error?

Comment: Because some ObjResults do not have xBrief, just xFull.

Comment: @JesseJ `ObjResults` is a class. All objects of this class have the same members. What am I missing?

Comment: ObjResult is a templated class. It represents about a 100 different possible classes. They do not all have the same members.

Comment: @JesseJ sorry, my bad. Editing

Comment: You still have a mismatch: ConvertIfHasXData vs ConvertIfHasBrief.  Also your classes are attempting to be specialized based on the template parameters to a member function.... I think you have the big picture right idea, but every detail here is dead wrong.

Comment: @MooingDuck ty for the `ConvertIfHasData`. The specialization on struct is intentional as I try to avoid specializing functions. Hope it is not wrong. Can't test it in a compiler right now.

Comment: @MooingDuck ty very much. What I meant (read: should have said) is I don't have the patience to write the test case and to debug the program online. But your code helped and motivated me. Ty

Comment: I had to change `static auto Convert( Obj const &xFrom, ObjResult &xTo )` to `static auto Convert( Obj const &xFrom, ObjResult &xTo ) -> CLStatus` and remove the `std::` from `void_t`, but it compiled. Thanks! It works! Although I'm not sure this is compatible with our older version of Solaris.

Comment: @JesseJ It can be done in all school C++ (except for `decltype` but ther are compiler extensions for that, like gcc's `typeof`)