# How to let C++ know that an operator has been overloaded for a class

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write a template function for which a particular type of classes have some functions or overloaded operators? For instance

```
template <typename T>
void dosomething(const T& x){
    std::cout << x[0] << std::endl;
}
```

In this context I'm assuming that x is a class that behaves like an array, that is, I have overloaded the `[]` operator as well as the `<<` so that it can work with `std::cout`.

The actual code that I have is slightly different but gcc is giving me

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

This must be because it doesn't know that I'm expecting `T` to be of some class that overloads the `[]` operator. Does anyone know if it is possible to overcome this? I'd like to let c++ know that the particular type `T` will have the `[]` overloaded.

Comment: You could try and make a typetrait that checks for the existence of member functions. The [pretty printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) features a selection of such typetraits. If you're happy with `*begin()` rather than `[0]`, you can use it right out of the box.

Comment: Did you declare the operator override method `const`?

Comment: Show the actual code.  If you are passing an object that overloads operator[], then you shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: @Jack, I did it like this: `T& operator[] (CIX i) {return _pt[i];} T  operator[] (CIX i) const {return _pt[i];}`. In any case, there might be other types that overloaded the operator and I'm expecting the function to handle this type of objects.

Comment: @Benjamin, I know that I shouldn't be getting this error. It would work fine if C++ knows of the definition. The problem is that the program won't know of its existence until later on. Someone else might create another class that overloads that operator and I want my function to be able to handle it.

Comment: @jmlopez You did mark the parameter as `const` so any methods you call on that object must be `const` as well.  Therefore, you can still handle any type of object that overloads that operator as long as the operator is marked `const`.

Comment: @jmlopez It looks like your method declaration doesn't specify the method as `const`.

Comment: @MrLunchtime, sorry, CIX is a macro. `#define CIX const unsigned int&`.

Comment: @jmlopez: Your function can handle any class that defines a const operator[] that returns a streamable value: http://codepad.org/3rpXoHdf

Comment: This facility is not available in C++, and still not in C++0x. CONCEPTS have been postponed (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to provide a little more detail, as this short example works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void dosomething(const T& x){
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void dosomething_else(const T& x){
    std::cout << x[0] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    dosomething< int >(1) ;
    std::vector< int > vec( 3, 1 );
    //dosomething< std::vector< int > >(vec);
    dosomething_else< std::vector< int > >(vec);
}
```

However, if you were to uncomment this line you would get a compiler error as std::vector doesn't implement the << operator:

```
//dosomething< std::vector< int > >(vec);
```

When you say this your thinking is on the right track:

> I'd like to let c++ know that the particular type T will have the []
>   overloaded.

However, the C++ compiler will actually search for [] operator at compile-time for any functions that request it. If there is no [] operator defined, you will get a compiler error. For example, this will cause a compiler error if inserted into the main() function:

```
dosomething_else< int >(1);
```

You get this error message, similar to what you suggest in the question:

```
test.cpp: In function 'void dosomething_else(const T&) [with T = int]':
test.cpp:19:   instantiated from here
test.cpp:11: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

You can actually check if the [] exists at compile-time using the method outlined in this question:
[How to check whether operator== exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534041/how-to-check-whether-operator-exists)

Comment: It seems that I do need to provide more details... I'll edit once I make a more concrete example.

Comment: James, Thank you for your helpful answer. Turns out that the mistake I was making was the order in which I defined the templates and the overloaded functions. For this reason it didn't find the definition of my overloaded operator. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181153/templates-function-overloading-and-their-order-of-appearence) to the other question I posted.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the method that declares the operator overload is marked `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1) define a simple class that has `[]` overloaded, inherit from it, and use that as the argument type instead of T.

2) cast the argument to some type that has your implementation of `[]`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `x[0]` use `x.operator[](0)`.

It won't be enough to overload operator `<<` for class T, you'll have to do it for the type that operator `[]` returns.

Comment: @Ajay, the question was specifically about a class that overrides `operator[]`. Don't make up requirements that aren't in the question.

Comment: First thing I didn't downvoted you. Secondly template should be generic, so assuming that target type is class is wrong assumption.