# Templates, function overloading and their order of appearence

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a simplified version of my code for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179062/how-to-let-c-know-that-an-operator-has-been-overloaded-for-a-class). In the process I encountered something that does not make sense to me. Can someone explain why I obtain the following result? Here is the code, it should compile and run in gcc.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::string;

template <typename T> inline char getType(const T&) {return 'S'; }
inline char getType(const char&) {return 'C';}
template <typename T> inline char getType(T*) {return 'A'; }

template <typename T> inline void writeData(const T& x) { 
    printf("Calling default writeData...\n");
    char type = getType(x);
    if (type == 'S') {
        printf("ERROR: binaryWrite::writeData ->  Structure not defined.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

template <typename T> inline void writeData(T* x, const unsigned int& len) { 
    printf("Writing array with writeData...\n");
    char type = getType(x[0]);
    std::cout << len << std::endl;
    if (type == 'S') {
        for (int i=0; i < len; ++i) {
            writeData(x[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i < len; ++i) {
            std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }   
}

class binaryWrite {
public:
    binaryWrite(void) {}
    template <typename T> 
    void write(const T& x, const char* name) { 
        writeData(x);
    }
};

inline void writeData(const string& s) {
    unsigned int len = s.size();
    const char* pt = s.c_str();
    writeData(pt, len);
}

int main () {
    string str = "Hello World";
    writeData(str);
    binaryWrite BF;
    BF.write(str, "str");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
manuel-lopezs-macbook-pro:binaryFiles jmlopez$ g++ -o example example.cpp
manuel-lopezs-macbook-pro:binaryFiles jmlopez$ ./example
Writing array with writeData...
11
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
Calling default writeData...
ERROR: binaryWrite::writeData ->  Structure not defined.
```

First it calls `writeData` with the string version. After I try calling that version with the `binaryWrite` function `write` (This function calls `writeData`) it calls the function defined by the template.

I played around with it and found out that if I move the overloaded function for the string right above the class definition of `binaryWrite` then I get the result that I want.

This is the change:

```
inline void writeData(const string& s) {
    unsigned int len = s.size();
    const char* pt = s.c_str();
    writeData(pt, len);
}

class binaryWrite {
public:
    binaryWrite(void) {}
    template <typename T> 
    void write(const T& x, const char* name) { 
        writeData(x);
    }
};
```

This is the output

```
Writing array with writeData...
11
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
Writing array with writeData...
11
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

It would seem as if `binaryWrite` did not know about the overloaded function `writeData` for `string` in the first case. But after the switch, since I defined the overloaded function first then it knows. Is this the right explanation?

What I would like to do eventually is use the macro `WRITESTRUCT` for other types but this definition would be in some other files so I won't be able to write them before the definition of `binaryWrite`. Any ideas how to overcome this problem if my explanation is indeed the right one?

Comment: @Bo, my apologies, I will edit it right now.

Comment: @Bo, I have deleted all the macros and the other functions. I think this is the minimum amount of code for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, playing around with your code, I found it also performs correctly if you move ALL of the `writeData` templates and overload below the `binaryWrite` class definition.

When the compiler encounters `binaryWrite::write`, it checks to see if it has a definition for `writeData` at that point.  It's selecting `template <typename T> inline void writeData(const T& x)` at that point because it only has access to the first two templates.  It then never goes back to see if there is a better choice.

When you move the writeData templates after binaryWrite, the compiler has no definition for writeData, and decides it will look again during template instantiation.   So when you then use `binaryWrite::write`, it picks the direct overload, instead of the template.

Comment: Thank you Dave. That makes sense. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to do it. This fixes the problem.

Comment: Hey Dave, sorry to bother you again, at some point I got my actual program to work in both OS X and Linux (god only knows how). Today I recently upgraded all of my code and it works well on my mac. But when I switch it to Linux then it gives me errors. I got it down to this question again. Turns out that the g++ in linux doesn't like it when you try to use `writeData` before it is declared, even if it is a template. In what operating system did you get the example to work? Sorry for bringing this up after more than 2 years.

Comment: @jmlopez: It's been a few years, so I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it was linux.  Your best bet is to forward declare all of the functions you are using.  That should allow the compiler to make the correct choice.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I had to follow Mooing Duck's advice and switch the function to a template specialization instead of an overload and in this way it works in both OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Your three functions are:

```
template <typename T> inline void writeData(const T& x);
template <typename T> inline void writeData(T* x, CIX len);
inline void writeData(const string& s);
```

I haven't any idea why `template<typename T> void write(const T& x, const char* name)` decided that the third option wasn't good enough, but the problem goes away if you make that third one into a template specialization of `writeData`, instead of an overload:

```
template <> inline void writeData<string>(const string& s);
```

Also, get rid of those macros.  I don't see how `WRITESTRUCT(string, s)` is clearer than `void writeData(const std::string& s)`, especially since there's no struct involved.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I got rid of all the macros in my edit. I'm still not sure if I should use template specialization. I've been told bad things about it and ever since then I decided not to. In any case, I think I'll have to go with this solutions. I hope I don't run into the problems described [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: I've read that actually, but rarely run into that problem.  Template specialization is a magical thing, but like all magic, must be carefully handled or you'll end the world.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct solution is to move the overloaded function, or at least its declaration, so that it is visible to binaryWrite.

Some compilers don't do this properly and include functions declared after binaryWrite, but before its use, in the set of overloads considered. This can lead to interesting ODR violations, if the set of visible functions are not the same in different places.

Comment: This is such a headache...I don't know for what type I will have to overload the function so there is no way for me to even declare it before binaryWrite. What are ODR violations?

Comment: ODR is the [One Definiion Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), saying that everywhere you use something, like your function, it must mean the same. If you have `binaryWrite::write<string>(..)` call *different* write functions in different places, that would be a violation and cause the program to be incorrect.