# C++: Enforcing template type implements a method

Tags: c++, templates, interface

I have a template class and I want to know if it is possible to enforce that the template class type implements a certain interface, in particular I want to enforce that the type overloads the `operator=` method. In Java I would write:

```
public class Tree<T implements IComparable>{
    public Tree(Vector<T> x){...}
}
```

What is the alternative in C++?

Comment: Actually, it is possible, using SFINAE and overloading tricks. [This answer gives you an idea of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6536204/51831).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write the code assuming that it does. If it doesn't, it will fail to compile when the user passes in the non-conforming type. There is no need for an explicit feature here. But why on earth would you ever need an interface like IComparable for this? Templates are duck typed.

But the template error might get nasty. You can use type traits and static assert to make this simpler. However, the Standard doesn't provide a trait like this, so you'd have to write one with SFINAE.

Comment: Not quite true. It will fail to compile only if that functionality is used. For example I could use `Tree<int>` and it would probably still compile even though it does not implement ICompareable. Or I could use `Tree<PLOP>` where PLOP does not implement ICompareable but for some reason my code did not insert any members (for example an incomplete test suite).

Comment: @LokiAstari: One could argue that DeadMG implied that with `Just write the code assuming that it does`.

Comment: @phresnel: A real word example: You may want to enforce that the type in standard vector is copyable. Otherwise certain things brake. But you can do `std::vector<auto_ptr<int> > x;` it will not break (even in testing) if you don't get the internal structure to re-size. So it is quite possible to have code that is fundamentally broken (but seems to work). I think the spirit of the question is that we want it to always break at compile time. Not break at compile time if we use some features.

Comment: If you never call the function, then you don't require it, do you?

Comment: @DeadMG: Very true. But that's a different question. The question is how to enforce a template parameter implements an interface. There are good reason to be able to do this (assuming you can't write the whole application in one day).

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer:

No; there is no language feature to do this.

### Shotish Answer:

The affect you want can be achieved using `SFINAE` and static asserts (asserts that are evaluated at compile time). Unfortunately this is a non trivial processes and requires a good understanding of template meta programming.

### Longish Answer:

The features was suggested for the new C++11 standard, but did not make it through the review process. Read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B) . At the current meeting (Portland Oct/12-19) Herb Sutter was suggesting that we should try for a two phase release (a minor followed by a new feature release) and concepts would be included in the first minor release. Whether this proposal is accepted will be available after the meeting.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Because both in C++03 and C++11, it was (and is) possible to check either that a template parameter has a specific operator overload, or that it derives from a specific interface, and either cause a hard compile error (via static assert) or soft SFINAE error. Concepts (although different people didn't agree on what should they be like) only tried to make "the official way" of what people already do eg. with the help of traits classes.