# C++: How to enforce the templated type to implement a certain operator(s)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20, type-traits

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933634/c-enforcing-template-type-implements-a-method) **from 9 years ago (C++11)** and maybe the newer standards provide this.

I would like to make sure that the templated class I am writing can be instantiated only if the type used implements certain operators, for example `<`.

```
template <typename T>
class XX {
private:
    T foo;
public:
    bool continiumTransfunctioneer(const T zoo){return zoo < foo;}
    // ...
};
```

I know that the code will fail to compile if that requirement is not met but the messages from the compiler can be quite verbose-I would like to be able to forewarn the users.

Comment: This is what C++ [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for using [C++20 concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
template <typename T>
  requires requires (const T& x, const T& y) { x < y; }
class XX {
 private:
  T foo;
 public:
  bool continiumTransfunctioneer(const T& zoo) const { return zoo < foo; }
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/xnWK1q94o)

Comment: Is "requires requires" a typo or actual syntax of this new-to-me construct?

Comment: @Vectorizer. [Why do we require requires requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200988/why-do-we-require-requires-requires)