# Check that two types cannot compare equal

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have two types, call them `A` and `B`.  I want to ensure that future developers do not change these types in such a way that they can compare equal.

To do so, I would like to add a unit test and a `static_assert` that ensure this property.  I am in c++03, and I have tried various template tricks like the following.

```
template <class Left, class Right>
struct can_compare_equal {
   typedef char True;
   typedef long False;

   template <class U>
   static U GetT() { Left* l; Right* r; return *r == *l; }

   template <class U> static True test(typeof(&can_compare_equal<Left,Right>::GetT<U>));
   template <class U> static False test(...);

   enum { value = sizeof(test<True>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to compile correctly.  Any advice?

Comment: The body of a method or function does not prevent it from being found, it just makes it an error to be found.  Have you thought about upgrading your compiler?  ;)

Comment: @Yakk: not really possible.  I'm stuck with gcc 4.2.1.  Also it should be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Comment: Ah, easy!  Compile gcc 4.9.2 with gcc 4.2.1.  Problem solved!  (I kid)  A problem is that `==` is not "a function", but rather an invocation of an operator. It could call a method, a function in some namespace, be found via ADL: heck it can be found via ADL in a way that there is guaranteed to be no other way to find it other than via ADL (the `friend operator` trick). The linked answer detects if a given class has a non-overridden method of a given name: it does not work in general!  `struct Evil{void a(){};void a(int){};};` That is not sufficient to determine if `A==B` is a valid expression.

Comment: Good point. I am really looking to ensure that no one does something dumb like make `A` derive from `B` or add an `A::operator==(const B&)`.  I guess I need to sharpen my question

Comment: then just `is_base_of` + `has_method_operator==_with_signature_blah` x2?  That reduces your question to a dupe of what you linked, no?  The general case cannot be solved in C++03, and the specific case is just a matter of which combination of specific cases (already solved) you want to cover.

Comment: Can't you just write your own version of `std::is_same`?

Comment: @black; that is not what I'm looking for.  My original question was broader than "are these types the same up to cv qualifiers".  See my previous comment starting with "Good point"

Comment: @JRG I see. Anyways, does the fact that you use `typeof` (which is a GCC extension) mean we can use other compiler-specific things?

Comment: The answer to this question would work (Add a template parameter to check between two differents types) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534041/how-to-check-whether-operator-exists

Comment: @Johnmph, this will work for non-member functions, I'm checking to see if it's modifiable to recognize `A::operator==(const B&) const`

Comment: @JRG It should work with member functions too. https://ideone.com/a0oBA0