# does int have an operator==

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm trying to check if a class has a method `operator==`. I found a solution with SFINAE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) and it's working fine with the class I make.

It looks like this :

```
template <typename T>
class comparable
{
    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;

    template <typename C> static one test( typeof(&C::operator==) ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);


public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

But, when I try :

```
std::cout << comparable<int>::value << std::endl;
```

Then it returns false while I was expecting it to return true. Why is this ?

Comment: About the question you had in there before your edit (what the three dots mean), look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c

Comment: What if `class C {...}; bool operator==(const C& a, const C& b) {...}`? Your code will say there is no operator==, because there isn't one within the class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`int` is not a class-type and has no member `operator==`, which is what you check for with your `&C::operator==`. Thus, the test yields a *"no"*. As others correctly pointed out, your test would also be negative for classes with only a non-member `operator==`.

How to correctly check whether an `operator==` exists has been asked here:
[How to check whether operator== exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534041/how-to-check-whether-operator-exists)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It doesn't tell him why his approach fails, so at least I won't Mjölnir it. But I agree, that was an easy 80 rep.

Comment: We're sons of Odin and have to be responsibly users of our powers. Well achieved, and congrats for the +80 (one 10 was from my side).

Answer (score 10):

Your immediate approach is flawed (or incomplete) for at least two fundamental reasons.

Firstly, your method checks whether *class* `C` has a *member* named `operator ==`. Non-class types will not pass this test, since they have no members whatsoever. And `int` is a non-class type.

Secondly, this approach by itself does not detect classes for which `operator ==` is implemented as a standalone function. For example, your test will say that `std::string` has no `==` operator. It is true that `std::string` has no such member, yet you can compare `std::string`'s for equality using the standalone `operator ==`. So, even if `int` somehow were a class type, it still does not mean that it would implement `operator ==` as a member function.

Answer (score 4):

Your test does not test if the expression `C==C` is valid. It tests if your class `C` has an `C::operator==`. Since `int` is no class it has no class-members.

Try testing e.g. `typeof(C()==C())`

Answer (score 0):

If you use c++11 you can use decltype which will make the implementation a lot easier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <class T, class Sfinae = void>
class comparable {
public:
   static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <class T>
class comparable <T, typename enable_if<is_same<decltype(declval<T>() == declval<T>()), bool>::value>::type> {
public:
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};

class A {
public:
   bool operator==(const A &) {
      return true;
   }
};

class B {
};

int main() {
   cout << comparable<int>::value << endl; // output: 1
   cout << comparable<A>::value << endl; // output: 1
   cout << comparable<B>::value << endl; // output: 0
}
```