# Understand C++11 solution for checking the existence of a member function

Tags: c++11

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860104

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
auto optionalToString(T* obj)
 -> decltype(  obj->toString()  )
{
    return     obj->toString();
}
auto optionalToString(...) -> std::string
{
    return "toString not defined";
}

struct TA
{
    std::string toString() const
    {
        return "Hello";   
    }
};

struct TB
{
};
```

Question> Given the proposed solution `optionalToString`, how I can use it to detect that TA has toString while TB doesn't.

Comment: it is quit hard to understand what is that you're asking

Comment: @DavidHaim I change the question and hopefully now you can read it.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"? in an `if constexpr (...)` context? When you want a string?

Comment: @Caleth, I mean how to check if a class has a member function

Comment: Do you want to know, how/why this solution works, or how you can use it, or how to adapt it to other member functions?

Comment: @chtz, I want to know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `can_apply` from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341824/3893262):

```
template<class T>
using toString_result = decltype(std::declval<T>().toString());

template<class T>
constexpr auto has_toString = can_apply<toString_result, T>::value;
```

Used like this:

```
struct TA
{
    std::string toString() const
    {
        return "Hello";   
    }
};

struct TB
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_toString<TA> << '\n';
    std::cout << has_toString<TB> << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21ed3050d98d3241)

Comment: The proposed solution looks simple too me. After all those complicate meta code, it doesn't look like a simple solution.

Comment: @q0987 It's a generalized solution which can be used for any operation. If you want to stick with yours, and the purpose is the detection, why not returning a boolean?

Comment: I found where the problem is. The online compiler doesn't generate the correct result and I thought the code doesn't work. It was the issue of the compiler instead of code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The given solution allows you to always get a string from any object. If it has a `toString()` member function, this will be used, otherwise, a default string. Usage example, given the above:

```
TA a;
TB b;
std::cout << "a: " << optionalToString(&a) << '\n';
std::cout << "b: " << optionalToString(&b) << std::endl;
```

However, you will not get a boolean value whether `a` or `b` has a `toString()` method. If you want that, you need something like the solution proposed by O'Neil.