# Is there a way test a type has "bool operator==(const type&, const type&)" in the compiling time?

Tags: c++

I write a class to test "type == type" but failed when type has no operator==;

```
template <typename _Type>
double _test(...){
    return 0;
}

template <typename _Type>
auto _test(_Type&& t)->decltype(t == t){
    return 0;
}

template <typename _Type>
struct has_equal_to
{
    static const bool value = sizeof(_test(std::declval<_Type>())) == sizeof(char);
};

struct test{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_equal_to<test>::value << std::endl; // compile failed ~~~~
    return 1;
}
```

has anyone can help ?
Or it is impossible to write a class like this .....

Comment: I *believe* it's possible. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae. I'll upvote the clever answerer who solves this!

Comment: Is `sizeof(char)` right? `sizeof(bool)` surely?

Comment: I guess same question already exist, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534041/how-to-check-whether-operator-exists?

Answer (score 7):

Your first `test` overload shouldn't be a template, as `_Type` can't be deduced and doesn't matter in that context anyway:

```
double _test(...){
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1c0ae57b9cde063)

---

You can achieve the same thing with a bit less boilerplate using C++17's [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) (which you can implement yourself easily for C++11):

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_equal_to : std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
struct has_equal_to<T, 
         std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>())>>
: std::true_type{};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73448024bf047cff)

---

Or you could use [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) for even less:

```
template <typename T>
using equal_to_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>());

template <typename T>
using has_equal_to = std::experimental::is_detected<equal_to_t, T>;
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c95ca07067dea70)

---

On an unrelated note, you shouldn't use names that begin with underscores; they're reserved to the implementation.