# Take as parameters only objects for which the operator+ is defined in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameter-passing

How can I take as parameter to the function only objects (and types, like int, double or float) for which the operator+ is defined in C++?

I am almost absolutely sure that the trick should be done somehow with the help of the template, but since I am very new to C++ I can not figure it by myself.

The example of such a function declaration would be very nice.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Can you show some of your research ?

Comment: You can just use a template and *assume* it has the operator. It will fail to compile at the point you try to use it. Is that good enough for you?

Comment: Your question looks like a variation on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534041/how-to-check-whether-operator-exists, but I like the approach @Kevin suggests above better. The compiler will catch it if you try to add a data type the doesn't have the "+" operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward solution, with `decltype`

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto func(T const& t, U const& u) -> decltype(t + u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

If you pass two objects which cannot be added, `decltype` will be ill-formed (as well as the *function-template*'s definition).

---

This was accepted, so I feel obligated to introduce a substantial improvement. Let's add perfect forwarding, as the comments suggested:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename U>
auto func(T&& t, U&& u) -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u)) {
    return std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u);
}
```

Pretty straightforward as well, despite being somewhat verbose. Turn `t` and `u` into *forwarding references*. Then use [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to make sure the value categories of the references are being preserved.

Comment: You don't even have to use `decltype` for this example. Just `return t+u` would suffice. I think the hard part of this question is executing actual summation.

Comment: @luk32 - I do need it in C++11.

Comment: What if another type is meant as a result? E.g. `void`? I think you assumed the requirements prematurely. Interesting would be, just to allow summable types, without doing the run-time summation. OP never said, they want to sum anything...

Comment: @luk32 - I think I understood the OP well. A function declaration that accepts two objects which have `operator +` defined. Both the return type and the body check for it separately. The OP didn't specify they wanted to *add them* either, did they?

Comment: Yes, they didn't. OP didn't make any requirements about the body, and the return type, it's your interpretation which makes the question trivially easy. I am just saying, it is far from general case.

Comment: @luk32 - You are free to post another approach. I'm sure it will fit the OP's request for an example. If your aim is for me to delete this post, I don't see why you bother.

Comment: My point is certainly not to make you delete your answer. It's good if you want to sum the stuff, not just accept summable stuff. I just point out you trivialized it. Don't you agree writing `t+u` for the compiler to evalute the expression makes it simple?

Comment: @luk32 - The compiler *will have* to evaluate the expression at some point or another. I'd be impressed if you can write a check for it that doesn't mention the `+` token at all.

Comment: @RichardHodges - Wanted to, but figured the dependency it brings isn't too relevant to the post. I'll revise it at some-point, if no better answer comes up.

Answer (score 5):

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class, class, class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};

  // C++17 has void_t.  It is useful.  Here is a short implementation:
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;

template<class A, class B>
using add_result = decltype( std::declval<A>()+std::declval<B>() );

template<class A, class B>
using can_add = can_apply< add_result, A, B >;
```

now `can_add<int, int>` is (inherited from) `std::true_type`, while `can_add<std::string, void*>` is (inherited from) `std::false_type`.

Now, if you are using a non-MSVC [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) compiler, this works:

```
template<class A, class B,
  std::enable_if_t<can_add<A&,B&>{}, int> =0
>
void only_addable( A a, B b ) {
  a+b; // guaranteed to compile, if not link
}
```

or

```
template<class A, class B>
std::enable_if_t<can_add<A&,B&>{}, void> // void is return value
only_addable( A a, B b ) {
  a+b; // guaranteed to compile, if not link
}
```

In [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a) the concept proposal will make much of this syntax cleaner.

There is a proposal for [`is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) which works like my `can_apply` above.

The `declval` part of the `add_result` is annoying.  Short of concepts, I'm unaware of how to remove it cleanly.

Comment: Didn't notice before that this trick is mentioned here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t. Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to extract this to a separate detector metafunction, it could look like

```
template <typename T>
struct is_addable
{
private:

    template <typename A, typename B = decltype(std::declval<A>() + std::declval<A>())>
    static std::true_type check (A *);

    template <typename A>
    static std::false_type check (...);

public:

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(check<T>(nullptr))::value;
};
```

Then, you can sfinae-constrain your function:

```
template <typename A, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_addable<A>::value>>
void func (A x, A y)
{
    // ...
}
```

This is the C++03 way. Yakk [presented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832292/2315602) a modern C++14 solution.

Comment: This reads like old C++03 ways of testing for the legality of an expression.

Comment: @Yakk If you know a better way, provide an answer with it, and I'll happily upvote it. Right now, your unconstructive critics is useless.

Comment: It is unconstructive criticism, not unconstructive critics.  Which would qualify as constructive criticism.  I'm just saying it reminds me of the way this was done before more modern machinery existed.  It works just fine (although, having the full power of `std::integral_constant<bool, ?>` with `constexpr` conversion and `()`  is often nice)

Comment: No need to be touchy. I'd wager Yakk wasn't critiquing, but was reminiscing.