# Could someone explain me the following template code?

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to template programming and I intend to use the solution here to make sure that the types used have an operator defined. But I would like to understand this code. I looked up information of cppreference but I am more confused on how this works.

[How to check whether operator== exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534041/how-to-check-whether-operator-exists)

Unfortunately it is quite cryptic to me and thought would ask for the meaning and reasons for some of the things in the code.

```
namespace CHECK
{
    struct No {};
    template <typename T, typename Arg>
    No operator==(const T&, const Arg&);

    /* Why are there two definitions of structures? Is this needed at all? Is
     * there a simpler version of this whole code snippet?
     */
    template <typename T, typename Arg = T>
    struct EqualExists {
        /* Why does this have to be a enum? What effect does this have? */
        enum {
            /* What happens if == sign is not defined for T? What would the
             * below comparison return when true/false? (The comparison *(T*)(0) == *(Arg*)(0))
             *
             * What is the need for No here? Why is it needed and how will
             * comparing it with the return type of == comparison be true ever?
             * How can the return type of == comparison and No structure be the same?
             */
            value = !std::is_same<decltype(*(T*)(0) == *(Arg*)(0)), No>::value
        };
    };
}
```

Could someone link this to the original question? Hope this helps someone new to cpp to understand this as well.

Comment: What are the outermost `{}`? A namespace, probably?

Comment: Yes. Let me fix it. Sorry about that

Comment: Or you can accept another template argument of type bool. If you need 2-3 switches, use an integer template argument and check bits. If you need more, use a class template argument, with a bunch of constexpr members to switch parts of your code. `if constexpr` is readable, C++ template metaprogramming is not.

Comment: "_Could someone link this to the original question?_" The fact that you included a link to the other question in yours achieves that already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/6534041?sort=newest

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Let's break it down step-by-step:

- `(T*)(0)` : pretend there's an object of type `T` at address 0; the type of this subexpression is a pointer
- `*(T*)(0)` : pretend there's an object of type `T` at address 0; the type of this subexpression is a reference, due to the asterisk in front dereferencing the pointer.  It looks kind of like a null pointer dereference, but more on that later.
- `*(Arg*)(0)` : pretend there's an object of type `Arg` at address 0; same pattern as T
- `*(T*)(0) == *(Arg*)(0)` : this is equivalent to calling `operator==<T, Arg>( *(T*)(0), *(Arg*)(0) )` with the additional convenience of [letting the compiler figure out where the operator is defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

  - If a user-defined `operator==` does not exist, then the `CHECK` namespace operator will be matched instead.  It's a "catch all" template.
- `decltype(*(T*)(0) == *(Arg*)(0))` : `decltype` says ["don't execute the subexpression in the parentheses; just give me its type"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).  In this case, the type is the return type of the `operator==` call.

  - No comparison operation actually occurs, nor any derefences into memory.
- `std::is_same<decltype(*(T*)(0) == *(Arg*)(0)), No>::value` : [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)'s `value` is `true` if the types are identical, or `false` otherwise.

  - `::value` is a static constexpr bool
  - The two type arguments are the `decltype(...)` and struct `CHECK::No`.
  - A real-world `operator==` typically returns bool.  Occasionally it may return a user-defined type.  It's unlikely that someone will write their custom `operator==` to return `CHECK::No`, and this code is relying upon that assumption.
- `enum { value = !std::is_same<...>::value }` : An enum is always a compile-time constant, works on older C++ compilers & specs (like C++03, where `constexpr` didn't exist), is compatible with `constexpr`, and does not require storage.

  - `static constexpr bool value = !std::is_same<...>::value;` would have been equivalent.

### Issues with the example code:

- *Technically* it's illegal to dereference a null pointer; [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is a safe alternative.
- *Technically* someone could write `CHECK::No operator==(const Foo&, const Bar&)`, which would fool the check into thinking the operator was undefined.
- The `operator==` in the CHECK namespace could shadow a globally defined operator== definition, resulting in a false negative.

### Alternative Implementation

To fix the above issues and "simplify", one method is to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).  Although "simpler" is subjective here.

[edit] Link to working version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9cc48729d53b6c6 , and updated code below

```
    template <typename T, typename Arg = T>
    class EqualExists {
        template <class U = T, class V = Arg, bool Exists = !!sizeof(std::declval<U>() == std::declval<V>())>
        static std::true_type Func(const T&, const Arg&);

        template <class U, class V>
        static std::false_type Func(const U&, const V&);

    public:
        static constexpr bool value = decltype(Func(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<Arg>()))::value;
    };
```

[edit] My original answer had a bug : did not use template args U and V in the Exists computation, and did fail to compile on gcc.  (worked on msvc for some reason)

```
        template <class U, class V, bool Exists = !!sizeof(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<Arg>())>
        static std::true_type Func(const T&, const Arg&);
```

Comment: @fifoforlife thank you so much for the explanation. Things are a lot more clearer now. 

"If a user-defined operator== does not exist, then the CHECK namespace operator will be matched instead. It's a "catch all" template." --> Does this mean that if == operator or type T is not defined then it would use the == operator defined in CHECK namespace? What would this be? Assuming this is some default operator defined by compiler would'nt we always get true from std::is_same?