# Check if T has operator<<

Tags: c++17

I am writing code to compare to instances of various types. The final comparison function is quite simple - with signature:

```
template <typename T>
int not_equal(const T& arg1, const T& arg2) {
    if (arg1 == arg2)
        return 0;

    std::cerr << "Error when comparing" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Now - I would like to add the actual values being compared in the `std::cerr` message as:

```
std::cerr << "Error when comparing " << arg1 << " != " << arg2 << std::endl;
```

however - many of the classes do not have `operator<<` - and that is OK. For the classes which do not support `operator<<` I just want the classname - i.e. the pseudo code should be something like:

```
if (supports_operator<<<T>)
    std::cerr << "Error when comparing " << arg1 << " != " << arg2 << std::endl;
else
    std::cerr << "Error when comparing instances of type: " << typeid(arg1).name() << std::endl;
```

Can I have my fictitious `supports_operator<<<T>()`functionality?

Edit: I am limited to C++17

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39348287/10794806

Comment: Why not used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6536204/1593077)? Should work just as well for `operator<<` as for `operator==`.

Comment: I am trying to go through the "check whether operator== exists" post; I must admit the answers are slightly above my C++ pay grade - although I agree I should be able to utilize the answers - looking into it.

Comment: Check this out: https://godbolt.org/z/j-WFTx

Comment: Thanks for the example - I think that solves.

Comment: Note: with `concepts` (available with gcc *before* C++20), you can overload a given function, for types accepting or not `<<`, in an automatic and very simple way. I prepared a simple answer, too late!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use C++20 and [`concepts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), then you can do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> 
concept Streamable = requires (T x) { std::cout << x; };

struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Foo const& obj) {
    // write obj to stream
    return os;
}

template <Streamable T>
void foo(T const& t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    Bar b;

    foo(f);
    foo(b); // error

    return 0; 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:25,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:25,selectionStartColumn:21,selectionStartLineNumber:25,startColumn:21,startLineNumber:25),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E+%0Aconcept+Streamable+%3D+requires+(T+x)+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+x%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Foo+%7B%7D%3B%0Astruct+Bar+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Astd::ostream%26+operator%3C%3C(std::ostream%26+os,+Foo+const%26+obj)+%7B%0A++++//+write+obj+to+stream%0A++++return+os%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3CStreamable+T%3E%0Avoid+foo(T+const%26+t)+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+t+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Foo+f%3B%0A++++Bar+b%3B%0A%0A++++foo(f)%3B%0A++++foo(b)%3B+//+error%0A%0A++++return+0%3B+%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.637075718015666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:37.5,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.362924281984334,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)